# NodeJS Code Coverage of Automated Tests

Tags: node.js, rest, testing, code-coverage

As part of a custom testing framework for a NodeJS REST API, I'd like to automatically detect when my tests are no longer providing proper coverage by comparing all *possible* outcomes with what the test suite received.

What methods exist for doing this? We can assume that it's being used for a REST API with a list of entry functions (API endpoints) that need coverage analysis, and each entry function will end with a known 'exit function' that responds to the requester in a standard way.

Here's what I've found so far:

**1: Basic solution (Currently implemented)**

- When writing each REST endpoint, manually create a list of all the possible outcome 'codes' [Success, FailureDueToX, FailureDueToY] for example
- After the tests have run, ensure every code in the list has been seen by the test suite for each endpoint.

***Pros:*** Very basic and easy to use; Doesn't change performance testing times

***Cons:*** Highly prone to error with lots of manual checking; Doesn't flag any issues if there are 5 ways to 'FailDueToX' and you only test 1 of them. Very basic definition of 'coverage'

**2: Static analysis**

- Parse the code into some sort of parse tree and look for all the instances of the 'exit function'
- Traverse up the tree until an API Endpoint is reached, and add that exit instance to the endpoint as an expected output (needs to keep a record of the stack trace to get there via a hash or similar)
- When tests are run, the endpoints return the stack trace hash or similar and this is compared to the expected output list.

***Pros:*** Automatic; Catches the different branches that may result in the same output code

***Cons:*** Generating the parse tree is non trivial; Doesn't detect dead code that never gets run; test suite needs to be kept in sync

**3: Profiling**

I've done this in the past on Embedded Systems with [GreenHills Code Coverage Tools](http://www.ghs.com/products/safety_critical/gcover.html)

- Start up a profiler like [dtrace](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/04/25/profiling-node-js/) and record the stack log for each test separately
- Parse the stack log and assign the 'test' to each line of code
- Manually analyse the code-with-annotations to find gaps.

***Pros:*** Semi Automatic; Gives more information about total coverage to a developer; Can see

***Cons:*** Slows down the tests; Unable to do performance testing in parallel; Doesn't flag when a possible outcome is never made to happen.

What else is there, and what tools can help me with my Static Analysis and Profiling goals?

Answer (score 1):

**Combinatorial testing** (different name suggestion would be appreciated)

- loosely based on idea of [QuickCheck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck)
- requires initial extraction of the endpoints (and static analysis mentioned in #2), creates list of all potential endpoints and arguments, and executes them
- validation:

  - light: app shall be stable to handle all possible inputs
  - strong: requires written specification regarding the endpoints to be able to validate against it

***Pros:***: Semi automatic (having proper tools)

***Cons:***: Specification validation is tricky. I'm not aware of existing implementation.

**Potentially helpful node modules:**

- [claire](https://npmjs.org/package/claire)
- [quickcheck](https://npmjs.org/package/quickcheck)